# How to deal with proportional independent variable that has many zeros and 100%s

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, proportion

I have data where the independent/predictor variable is a proportion (i.e., % of cognitive task trials on which speech used to support performance) and contains many zeros and many 100%. In some cases I'm looking at the bivariate relation between age and % speech, and in other cases I'm using % speech to predict performance on another task, and generally am including other predictors in the model.

I'm guessing I may run into problems if my model residuals/errors are non-normal. In which case, what is recommended? Would it make sense to transform the speech variable or to treat it as dichotomous or something similar instead of as a continuous variable?

Comment: You don't specify what you mean by "looking at the bivariate relation" but in the second part speech is a predictor, not a response, so I don't really see how the residuals would be the issue either way there -- that's not what would make the residuals non-normal (except insofar as you might fit a model that doesn't correctly describe the relationship; that would be the fault of the model, not of leaving the intermediate percentages alone).

Comment: Note that no-one worries too much about the limiting case of this problem, which is an indicator variable as predictor. Otherwise, why throw away information?

Comment: @Glen_b, re: looking at bivariate relation, I meant just looking at the correlation without any other predictors in the model. I think the reason for my concern is that one could imagine the direction of influence going the other way, and the speech variable being the response variable, in which case for sure linear modeling would be considered wrong, correct?

Comment: There's no issue whatever calculating a correlation, of course. If you test it and then decide to use some test that relies on bivariate normality that might be an issue, but such assumptions can be avoided. On the other hand if there are other likely-to-be-relevant covariates that could impact the relationship I'm not sure there'd be much value in looking at the marginal correlation (which might easily be the opposite sign to the partial correlation, or be zero when the partial correlation is substantial). The marginal relationship could depend on the particular arrangements of the covariates